# Не могу связать сущности в Java

Tags: java

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Could
> not determine type for:
> ru.se.ed.domain.Client, at table:
> demand, for columns:
> [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(client)]

Demand.java

```
package ru.se.ed.domain;
import javax.persistence.*;
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "demand", schema = "public", catalog = "db_cred")
    public class Demand {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        private long id;
        public long getId() { return id; }
        public void setId(long id) {this.id = id;}

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", nullable = false)
        private Client client;
        public Client getClient() { return client; }
        public void setClient(Client client) { this.client = client; }
    }
```

Client.java

```
package ru.se.ed.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "client", schema = "public", catalog = "db_cred")
public class Client {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;
    public long getId() { return id;}
    public void setId(long id) {this.id = id;}

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "fname")
    private String fname;
    public String getFname() {return fname;}
    public void setFname(String fname) {this.fname = fname;}
}
```

Вроде ничего сложного, посмотрел примеры ...
Данные из одной таблицы возвращаются нормально, но когда указываешь `@ManyToOne` с другой получаю ошибку.

Comment: У вас первичный ключ клиента - id, а в связи вы указываете client_id. Вот и все

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите пример связи User и UserRole в [тык](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hibernate-annotation-example/) этом примере. Так же рекомендуют все же ставить аннотации сущности на геттеры.

Comment: Аннатации на геттеры это как?

Comment: @Id
@Column(name="id")
public int getId()...

Comment: А у меня разве не та?

Comment: Тоже самое и написано